# Why compiler can not optimize std::string concat?

Tags: c++, string, gcc, clang

I try such simple code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   const std::string s = std::string("a") + "b";
   puts(s.c_str());
   return 0;
 }
```

I expect that compiler(gcc 4.8.2/clang 3.5.0) optimize such code to

```
 int main()
 {
   puts("ab");
   return 0;
 }
```

But I can not get such result, I try different options like "-Ofast", "-flto", "-static-libstdc++", but always see in disassembler output three functions call:

```
...
callq  0x4017e0 <_ZNSsC2EPKcRKSaIcE>
... 
callq  0x401690 <_ZNSs6appendEPKc>
...
callq  0x401490 <_ZNSs4_Rep10_M_disposeERKSaIcE>
```

The first one is call to std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&).

So are any compiler around, that can optmize such code to just puts("ab");
or at least to "std::string s("ab");"?

And if there are no such compiler, what make such optimization difficult to implement?

**Update**
About real world usage.
I see/saw many places in real code with such pattern:

```
  std::string s = std::string(string_const1) + string_const2 + string_variable + string_const3;
```

And if performance is important, of course it is possible to rewrite
such code in more optimal ways.

But modern compilers do great jobs to optimize code.
And gcc, for example have __builtin functions for malloc/free/strcpy/strcat and so on. And if std::basic_string from libstdc++ from gcc use them this functions(malloc,free,strcpy,strcat) for part of implementation, why not predict the result of functions usage and give answer.

Comment: Because C++ class constructors and operators are functions, they are not algebraic, thus it is difficult to detect algebraic optimizations.

Comment: You didn't say why you want to do this, but would 'const std::string s = "a" "b";' fit your needs?  String literals auto paste when written next to each other.

Comment: To be clear, the C++ standard permits the program to be optimized to `puts("ab");` or equivalent. But compilers don't do it. I guess you would have to ask a compiler developer, but perhaps part of it has to do with respecting the wishes of the programmer. If they followed the *as-if* rule ultimately then there would be a  lot of complaints; e.g. making a system call to write something on the screen, or do a sleep, has no observable behaviour as per the definition in C++14.

Answer (score 8):

`std::string` involves dynamic allocation of storage and, in most cases, an extremely complex implementation and can therefore not be reduced to compile-time semantics, no matter how well the compiler has constant folding down to a fine art.

However: If your `string` is actually declared like this why didn't you use a `char` array in the first place but chose `string`?
If you need to work with some strings to produce others, there are still tools that can do that job with `char` arrays, especially since C++11 introduced variadic templates and `constexpr`. A future version of C++ will hopefully also introduce [`std::string_literal`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4121.pdf) to further ease that.

Comment: Would it be possible to use C++14 features to have a constexpr std::string::operator+ and implement OP's request?

Comment: @liori I should think so since `string_literal` is based on C++14.

Comment: There is also the complicating issue that GCC's `std::string` is still copy-on-write.

Comment: @T.C. ... with C++11?

Comment: @Columbo Yes. It's non-conforming, but changing it would be ABI-breaking.

Comment: >why didn't you use a char array in the first place but chose string? Because of it is not real code, and where code similar to above occurs  , it is not worth manual optimization, but I am curios why compiler can not optimize it for me.

Comment: It could be nice to elaborate a bit more about — why the optimization can not be reduced in a compile time even with `-flto`. But ⁺¹ anyway for the linked paper, it seems to be interesting.